# Multiple wavesurfer instances on one page

Tags: html, jquery, wavesurfer.js

I have multiple instances of wavesurfer player on one page.

i need to pause all players when I click "play" a certain player

How to make it so that when the player is playing, all other players pause?

Here is html code:

**HTML:**

```
    <center>
        <p>Track 1</p>
        <div class="player">
            <div id="controls1" class="controls">
                <i class="fa-thin fa-circle-play" id="playPause1" data-src="{{ file.id }}.mp3"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <span id="currentTime1">00:00</span>
            </div>
            <div class="download">
                <a href="">download</a>
            </div>
            <div id="waveform-body1" class="waveform-body">
                <div id="loadingBox1" class="waveform-loading-box">Click play button to load and listen</div>
                <div id="waveform1" class="waveform"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

        ...

        <p>Track X</p>
        <div class="player">
            <div id="controlsX" class="controls">
                <i class="fa-thin fa-circle-play" id="playPauseX" data-src="{{ file.id }}.mp3"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="time">
                <span id="currentTimeX">00:00</span>
            </div>
            <div class="download">
                <a href="">download</a>
            </div>
            <div id="waveform-bodyX" class="waveform-body">
                <div id="loadingBoxX" class="waveform-loading-box">Click play button to load and listen</div>
                <div id="waveformX" class="waveform"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </center>
```

Here is javascript:

**Javascript:**

```
    <script>
        (function($) {
            var playPause = document.querySelector('#playPause1');
            var currentTime = document.querySelector("#currentTime1");
            var loadingBox = document.querySelector("#loadingBox1");

            var timeCalculator = function (value) {
                second = Math.floor(value % 60);
                minute = Math.floor((value / 60) % 60);
                
                if (second < 10) {
                    second = "0" + second;
                }

                return minute + ":" + second;
            };

            var wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
                container: '#waveform1',
                backend: 'MediaElement',
                waveColor: '#6AA6CB',
                progressColor: '#487698',
                cursorColor: '#6AA6CB',
                cursorWidth: 0,
                barWidth: 1,
                responsive: true,
                height: 50,
                hideScrollbar: true,
                maxCanvasWidth: 4000,
                barRadius: 0,
                fillParent: true,

            });

            wavesurfer.song = "track1.mp3"

            wavesurfer.load(wavesurfer.song)

            //play track
            playPause.onclick = function(){
                playPause.classList.remove("fa-circle-play");
                playPause.classList.add("fa-circle-pause");
                wavesurfer.playPause();
            }

            wavesurfer.on('error', function(e) {
                console.warn(e);
            });

            //show loading percentage
            wavesurfer.on('loading', function(x){
                loadingBox.innerText = "Loading: " + x + "%";
            });

            //remove loading text and play
            wavesurfer.on("ready", function(e){
                loadingBox.classList.remove("waveform-loading-box");
                loadingBox.classList.add("waveform-loading-box-hidden");
                
            });

            //change play button to pause on plying
            wavesurfer.on("play", function(){
                playPause.classList.remove("fa-circle-play");
                playPause.classList.add("fa-circle-pause");
            });

            //change pause button to play on pause
            wavesurfer.on("pause", function () {
                playPause.classList.remove("fa-circle-pause");
                playPause.classList.add("fa-circle-play");
            });

            //get updated current time on play
            wavesurfer.on("audioprocess", function () {
                currentTime.textContent = timeCalculator(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
            });

            //update current time on seek
            wavesurfer.on("seek", function () {
                currentTime.textContent = timeCalculator(wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
            });

            //stop player
            wavesurfer.on('finish', function(){
                playPause.classList.remove("fa-circle-pause");
                playPause.classList.add("fa-circle-play");
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

Also after finish playing track switch to next track

Comment: Hi, why do you include CSS? It's not relevant here

Comment: For your question, you need to: 1) obtain a reference to all wavesurfer objects 2) in a loop, call `wavesurfer.stop()` on every object 3) call `wavesurfer.play()` for the target song.  
 
For autoplaying the next track, you need to listen to wavesurfer event `finish`